# Truncating too long varchar when inserting to MySQL via SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am inserting data to MySQL via SQLAlchemy models. Recently, this app is running against MySQL configured with `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and app fails occasionally because of *Data too long for column* error.

I know that I can disable **strict** sql_mode for my session (like here [MySQL too long varchar truncation/error setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459184/mysql-too-long-varchar-truncation-error-setting)),

but I was curious if SQLAlchemy can enforce max String() length for column data. Documentation says, the `String()` length is for `CREATE TABLE` only. My question:

1. Is it possible to enforce max length (truncate too long strings) in SQLAlchemy?
2. Can I set it **for individual columns** or for all columns in all tables/database only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you would like to `enfoce` max length by automatically truncating it on the python/sqlalchemy side, I think that using [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators) is the easiest way to achieve this:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String(4))
    name = Column(String(10))

    @validates('code', 'name')
    def validate_code(self, key, value):
        max_len = getattr(self.__class__, key).prop.columns[0].type.length
        if value and len(value) > max_len:
            return value[:max_len]
        return value
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this apply to many models / tables?

Comment: @YaakovBressler: sure, just extract the code you want into a base class, or a mixin class.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic solution based on [van's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368674/10871073):

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

def TruncateString(*fields):
    class TruncateStringMixin:
        @validates(*fields)
        def validate_string_field_length(self, key, value):
            max_len = getattr(self.__class__, key).prop.columns[0].type.length
            if value and len(value) > max_len:
                return value[:max_len]
            return value

    return TruncateStringMixin
```

Now you can use it with

```py
class MyTable(Base, TruncateString('code', 'name')):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String(4))
    name = Column(String(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a TypeDecorator in your base model for an even more generic answer. Then, use this TypeDecorator instead of string.

In base.py

```
 from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

  class TruncateString(TypeDecorator):
    """trim spaces from the string"""

    impl = db.String
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        # In case you have nullable string fields and pass None
        if value and len(value) > self.impl.length:
            value = value[:self.impl.length]
        return value if value else value

    def copy(self, **kw):
        return TruncateString(self.impl.length)
```

Now, in your yourModel.py, use this type.

```
    from flask_app.models.base import *

class CampaignScript(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'campaign_script'

    name = Column(TruncateString(200))
    subject = Column(TruncateString(200))
    comments = Column(TruncateString(200))
    language = Column(TruncateString(200))
    script = Column(NVARCHAR(None))
    user_id = Column(TruncateString)
    account_id = Column(Integer)
    comm_type = Column(TruncateString(45))
    short_name = Column(TruncateString(75))
    released_locked = Column(Boolean())
```

good luck